# How to insert data to columns from PHP into MariaDB?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am familiar with MySql databases but there is this new database called MariaDB. I try to insert data there from PHP code and I can't, so can you help me insert the data?  My PHP on the server is 5.4.32 and my MySQL version is 10.0.20-MariaDB-cll-live.

This is the code that I am using to try to insert data into MariaDB.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("database", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if($name !=''||$email !=''){
       //Insert Query of SQL
       $query = mysql_query("insert into VIP Membership(Name, Email) values ('$name', '$email')");
       echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
    }
    else{
       echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
    }
}

mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
```

EDIT: I used the mysqli code now but it throws me an error 500.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_table";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
if($name !=''||$email !=''){

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'VIP Membership' (Name, Email)
VALUES ('$name', '$email')";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You need to surround your table name in backticks, since it has a space in it.  ``INSERT INTO `VIP Membership`(`Name`, `Email`) VALUES (?, ?);``

Comment: P.S. This code is unsafe.  You should *not* be using `mysql_query` and friends anymore.  You should consider upgrading to MySQLi or PDO and switching to prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you man, btw if a username of the server has @localhost at the end I need to add that to the username in the code or just what it is on the left of the @

Comment: Mmm you were right I checked on the right side of phpmyadmin and said extension: mysqli @RocketHazmat

Comment: In the PHP code, you shouldn't need the `@localhost`, just what's on the left of the `@`.

Comment: That means the phpMyAdmin application is using MySQLi.  Your code should too.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Check out my last answer here man please it throws me an error now

Comment: Don't post that as an *answer*.  It doesn't **answer** the question, does it?  [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33266171/edit) that into your question.

Comment: Sorry man I am new around here, I deleted the answer and I modified the question can you check it please man? :( @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use *backticks* (not single quotes) to surround your table name, since it has a space in it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `VIP Membership` (Name, Email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
```

UPDATE: You should *really* be using prepared statements.  As it stands, this code is very unsafe.

```
$sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO `VIP Membership` (Name, Email) VALUES (?, ?)");
if($sql !== FALSE){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "ss", $name, $email);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)){
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_stmt_error($sql);
    }
} else{
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: Man still throwing me the same error :( can we talk in a kind of chat? @RocketHazmat

Comment: What error is it giving you?  Do you see any MySQL errors?  Are you sure it's not a syntax error in PHP?  Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` and see if you get an error message?

Comment: Also make sure you're not missing any `;`, `}`, `)`, etc.

Comment: Mm don't worry man I think I fix it I did one mistake @RocketHazmat

Comment: @RocketHazmat exactly `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` that one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, how can I give you a feedback or something? @RocketHazmat is the less that I can do to pay you this

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not just because there's a space in there, but they're using single quotes `INSERT INTO 'VIP Membership'` ;-) instead of ticks.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: He wasn't using single quotes in the 1st example, though.

Comment: @RocketHazmat ah yeah, you're right. I checked the question's revisions. Either way, you're *bang on* ;-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat how can I give you a feedback or something man? This was really useful and now I solved my problem, you helped me a lot seriously

Comment: @CarlosDams: Glad I could help.  If you want to give feedback, then upvote and/or accept this answer.  Otherwise, just knowing I was helpful is feedback enough.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB is a backward compatible, binary drop-in replacement of MySQL. That means  MariaDB version will work exactly like MySQL. You don't have to do anything specific to make your MySQL code to work on MariaDB. But in your code I would use the `mysqli` function (or PDO) instead of the old deprecated `mysql` one.

As you may encounter some incompatibilities you can check this official document for differences between the two. [MariaDB vs MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/)

Answer (score -1):

check your brackets {  insert code here } if this thing is not arranged properly it brings out an error