# Data is not getting inserted in mysql.where is it wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, sql-insert

```
    $value1=$_POST['name'];
    $value1=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value1);
    $value2=$_POST['addr'];
    $value2=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value2);
    $value3=$_POST['phone'];
    $value3=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value3);
    $value4=$_POST['type'];
    $value4=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value4);
    $value5=$_POST['qty'];
    $value5=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value5);

    $sql1= "INSERT INTO guests       ('Name','Address','phone','pizza_type','quantity') VALUES ('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5')";

    $records1=mysqli_query($link,$sql1)  or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link). " in ".$sql1);

     $sql2="SELECT * FROM 'guests'";
$records2=mysqli_query($link,$sql2) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link)." in ".$sql2);
```

Comment: Edit question and paste your code. Do not add image of your code

Comment: Copy paste your code under your question don't link images of your code and format the error's with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Change

```
$sql1= "INSERT INTO guests ('Name','Address','phone','pizza_type','quantity') VALUES ('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5')";
```

To

```
$sql1= "INSERT INTO guests (`Name`,`Address`,`phone`,`pizza_type`,`quantity`) VALUES ('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5')";
```

**2)** Change

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM 'guests'";
```

To

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM `guests`";
```

`Single quotes` are not allowed to enclose column name or table name. Instead, use `backtick`.

**Find Backtick**

[image]

Comment: you told no change

Comment: You are not able to see the difference? Strange. There is a huge difference between single quotes and backtick. @Diksha

Comment: You miss $sql2="SELECT * FROM guests"; Please update your answer

Comment: @NanaPartykar ji

Comment: Yes @Diksha Ji? If it helped. Then, please mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily.

Comment: uff...this is the first time i am using this site to ask questions..embarrassed! I'll just do it.

Comment: You did for someone else answer @Diksha.

Comment: @NanaPartykar can you please solve a problem i just have posted

Comment: @Diksha Give me question link.

Comment: it drove me crazy by not accepting my code..so i deleted it..btw good to see you..but i have another question for you..i'll just post if it accepts!

Answer (score 0):

Use **backtick** (`) on table name.

```
$sql1= "INSERT INTO `guests`....";
...
$sql2="SELECT * FROM `guests`";
```

More: [How to insert data to columns from PHP into MariaDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266171/how-to-insert-data-to-columns-from-php-into-mariadb)

Comment: it didnt help either

Answer (score 0):

### Updated remove single quotes from query

```
1. $sql1= "INSERT INTO guests (Name, Address, phone, pizza_type, quantity) VALUES ('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5')";


2. $sql2="SELECT * FROM guests";
```